# What's a clean formatting for multiple nested connect and graphql calls in javascript?

Tags: javascript, apollo-client

I'm looking for advice on how to cleanly format multiple nested connect and graphql statements for readability and ease of typing.  As you can see, wrapping each call gets pretty ungainly to look at.  Is there a suggested shortcut/trick/formatting when you have multiple nested connect/graphql statements?

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(graphql(signinUserGql, {name: 'signIn'})(graphql(registerUserGql, {name:'register'})(LoginScreen)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is so subjective but I like to:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
  graphql(signinUserGql, {name: 'signIn'})(
    graphql(registerUserGql, {name:'register'})(LoginScreen)
  )
);
```

For me, I can clearly see the `graphql` invocations and the params for each.

Comment: Yeah, this makes more sense than line-breaking on the braces.

Answer (score 0):

There are several online Javascript code formatting tools.  They all appear to be recommending this:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(graphql(signinUserGql, {
    name: 'signIn'
})(graphql(registerUserGql, {
    name: 'register'
})(LoginScreen)));
```

http://jsbeautifier.org/
http://www.danstools.com/javascript-beautify/